# Beamer: placing text on four sides of an image using tikzpicture, however picture and text move at the same time

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, graphics

I am trying to place some text around an image like this:
[image]

And this is done using tikzpicture.

However, as soon as I change (x,y) in

```
        \node[align=center] at (x,y) {left};
```

Both the box and the text move at the same time!

I know this probably has something to do with the "align=center" option, but I am not sure how to change it so they are not moving at the same time.

Can someone please help!

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
     \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{box}};
            \node[align=center] at (-2,5) {up};
            \node[align=center] at (-2,1) {down};
            \node[align=center] at (1,-1) {left};
            \node[align=center] at (3,-1) {right};
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could position the elements relative to the page:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
     \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
            \node (image) at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image}};
            \node[align=center,yshift=3cm] at (current page.center) {up};
            \node[align=center,yshift=-3cm] at (current page.center) {down};        
            \node[align=center,xshift=-4cm] at (current page.center) {right};   
            \node[align=center,xshift=4cm] at (current page.center) {left};                               
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

---

Or you could place an invisible square which is large enough to encompass all elements of your image:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
     \begin{tikzpicture}
        \path (-4,-3.5) rectangle (4,3.5);
            \node (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image}};
            \node[align=center] at (0,3) {up};
            \node[align=center] at (0,-3) {down};
            \node[align=center] at (-3.5,0) {left};
            \node[align=center] at (3.5,0) {right};
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

---

If you don't mind that your labels will stick out into the margin, you could also exclude them from the bounding box of your image:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
     \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image}};
            \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
            \node[align=center] at (0,3) {up};
            \node[align=center] at (0,-3) {down};
            \node[align=center] at (-3.5,0) {left};
            \node[align=center] at (3.5,0) {right};
            \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```